# Comparing prepostest different observational categories

Tags: categorical-data, observational-study

Two groups of individuals are subjected to two different treatments. We have video recordings of them pre and post treatment. Observational categories are registered every minute for a series of dimensions. What statistical test would you carry out to see if both groups change in the same way, i.e., proportion of behaviours in each category change in the same way for both groups between pre and postest?

Answer (score 0):

One common way to analyze this is to express each type of behaviour as a difference from its pre-test average and do repeated-measures ANOVA/MANOVA or its equivalent free of distributional assumptions if the data are not normally distributed. Depending on whether observational categories are dependent or independent, whether pre-test behaviour variability is of interest, and whether you expect the change in behaviours to be non-linear (also, what is the hypothesis behind 'change in the same way' - direction of response, shape of response), different approaches may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to test a time by treatment interaction. To further explain, it seems like the question is asking how do I test whether the measure of effect (say treatment A vs. B) is the same at pre-test as it is at post-test. To do this you would need an interaction term in your linear model which would allow the effect size to vary between pre and post test measurements. Then to test whether the effect size at pre-test is the same as the effect size at post-test, you would need to test whether the interaction = 0. If the outcome is not continuous, then this would need to be within a generalized linear model.

Comment: While this responds to the question, it's a little brief for an answer (one sentence answers are generally regarded as more like a comment). Could you expand on your answer a little?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but would you mind editing your answer to contain it?   (select and copy your comment, click on 'edit' under your answer and paste in everything from `To further explain` onward).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Responding to some issues, the categories are dependant and mutually exclusive. I am inclined to treat them as count frequencies rather than compute averages. I was considering approaching the issue with loglinear modelling, to analyze the interactions you are mentioning.